# "using host libthread_db library" gdb debugger is not included

Tags: c, debugging, ubuntu, gcc, gdb

I am newbie for programming. I have tried to compile C file using Linux Ubuntu terminal by this command:

> gcc -g test.c

After compiling I then start debugging

> gdb -q ./a.out

to debugging my C file. I'm reading the programming book but the book said that I should have "Using host libthread_db library "/lib/tls/i686/cmov/libthread_db.so.1"" popup right after I start to debugging by using gdb. At first I ignored it but later on I could not debug some of the example from the book.

How can I update this debugger?

Answer (score 0):

> the programming book but the book said that I should have "Using host libthread_db library "/lib/tls/i686/cmov/libthread_db.so.1"" popup

The book is wrong:

- GDB is a command-line program, it doesn't do popups
- You should only get a message about `libthread_db` *if* you are debugging a multi-threaded program (and you don't appear to be doing that).

> later on I could not debug some of the example from the book

You should ask a separate question, showing exactly what "I could not debug" means.

Comment: By popups, I meant it should show in my terminal after start the command gdb. How can I multi-threaded? I've tried to compile with command gcc -fno-builtin test.c -lpthread but it doesn't work.

Comment: @PizzaPat You continue to ask questions that say "it didn't work", but don't say *what* you did, and *what* didn't work. In programming, details *matter*. You better start providing details, or you are not going to get useful answers.